# Python RegEx for Komodo to organize 4000 contacts

Tags: python, regex, facebook, contacts, komodo

I have a huge number of approximately 4000 contacts.
I imported most of my Facebook contacts into my main address book in Google, but now I have contacts with a special field "Facebook : facebook.pseudonym", which is unusable, and I want to transform all of them in mail address like facebook.pseudonym@facebook.com, that I can use in my newsletters.

In order to do that, I tried with Komodo to use regex in their "find & replace" to select the field after ",Facebook," but as there is sometime an EOL, sometime a comma, sometime something else.

Could you help me find the good expression to reorganize all my contacts ?

Thanks,
Yann

Comment: Komodo comes with excellent Rx Toolkit, which you could use to perfect your regex (it is better to teach you how to fish, rather than give you just one fish).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following regex:

**(,)*Facebook\s+:\s*(?\w+.\w+)**

I used [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/hncl11M0RP) to test the regex. I'm not sure if it will works for python.

Comment: Assuming that you could have some string like:

Facebook : facebook.pseudonym afas
, Facebook : facebook.pseudonym
Facebook : facebook.pseudonym
     , Facebook : facebook.pseudonym
,Facebook : facebook.pseudonym

The regex that works to get the contact name is:

**(,)*Facebook\s+:\s*(\w+.\w+)**

I tested this regex [here](http://www.pythonregex.com/)

The regex is the same just have not use named captured grouping.

I hope this works for you!!!